# Installing external packages in golang

Tags: go, github

I am trying to import a package in my golang code. But it is showing me this error:

> cannot find package "github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch" in any of:
>   /opt/go/src/github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch (from $GOROOT)
>   /chaincode/input/src/github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch (from $GOPATH)
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch "

Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Install the package with `go get`

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html

Comment: [How to Write go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: @Flimzy, yes I have used Go Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck your environment variables(`$GOPATH`, `$GOROOT`).

The problem you are facing is that, your code is searching for the package `github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch` in `/opt/go/src/github.com/`, `/chaincode/input/src/github.com/` and `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/` directories. But you have installed the package in `C:\Users\xyz\go\src\github.com` directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this.
Can you tell me how to access /opt/ folder

Comment: I'am using windows system and I thought /usr/local/ is same as /opt/

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your `$GOPATH` environment variable is set up correctly.

Then double check the packages are installed, if not you need to install the package which you can do with.

`go get github.com/mattbaird/jsonpatch`

Comment: Yes, I have taken care of this already.
I have set GOROOT with 'C:\Go\'
I have also set GOPATH to the location where I have written my gocode.
I have written my Gocode outside the 'C:\Go\' folder at the location 'C:\Users\xyz\src' .  So the GOAPTH is set to the same value. But still it is showing the same error.

Comment: The packages are installed properly inside the go folder at the location 
'C:\Users\xyz\go\src\github.com'.